# php - if css div class exists in body, add stylesheet to head

Tags: php, if-statement, head

I need to add a stylesheet to my head, if a div class exists in my body.

i.e.

If this exists in my body:

```
<div class="myclass">...</div>
```

Add this to my head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/mystyle.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

How do I do this with php?

Comment: You can do it using javascript or jqury...I dont think you can do it using PHP as head loads before the body

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php (note that you'll have to process the entire document in the DOM and not just stream it as text as is usual for PHP programs)

Comment: Php serves the document.  For post serve document manipulation use js. When would you have div without already knowing its class while creating head?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

check this url once [click](http://www.vidalquevedo.com/how-to-load-css-stylesheets-dynamically-with-jquery)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

if($("#myclass").size()>0){
        if (document.createStyleSheet){
            document.createStyleSheet('style.css');
        }
        else {
            $("head").append($("<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'   type='text/css' media='screen' />"));
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: we use this idea to slove the problem